# fancybox: callbacks issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to make another fancybox() call on a callback like afterClose?Actually what I intent to do is once I close the fancybox window I again need to call a new fancybox() in order to display some images.

The method I tried was: // the structure code below

```
jQuery("#view_images").fancybox({
 afterClose : show_images
});
```

Here show_images is a method that again calls a fancybox() to display image slideshow. But I get an error in my console "too much recursion". 
Could anybody give me some pointers on how to go about it or am I heading the wrong way.
Any advice on this regard would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to correct the proper syntax of `afterClose` ... and second you would need to give fancybox some time to close the first box before trying to open the second, otherwise it will crash your browser so try this:

```
afterClose: function(){
 setTimeout("show_images()",400);
}
```